# Power Shell Error Trapping

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, office365

I can't figure out why powershell will not trap errors when running a script against office365 (Exchange online). I receive the raw error message each time, despite my try and catch blocks.

```
Foreach ($groups in $groups)
{
try 
{
    Add-DistributionGroupMember "$Groups" -Member "$UserName" -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck -ErrorAction Stop
    #write-host "Added user $userName to $Groups";
}

Catch 
{
    Write-Output "`t   $userName is already a member of $Groups."   
}

}
```

Comment: Try removing `-ErrorAction Stop`, I believe that is what is preventing it from falling in the catch.

Comment: The -ErrorAction Stop causes any error that the command throws to be treated as a terminating error. Try-Catch blocks are specifically for handling terminating errors so I don't that is the issue.

Comment: @Matt - do you see an error and your output from the catch block?

Comment: Seeing the error message would be very important to help with troubleshooting.

Comment: When you run this code, do you see the output from the catch block or not?

Comment: Also I will point out that while it is syntactically valid, using $groups as the object variable name **and** the collection variable name is confusing and just plain silly.

Comment: The recipient "testuser@xx.org" is already a member of the group "Everybody".
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (testuser@xx.org:RecipientWithAdUserGroupIdParameter`1) [Add-Distri
   butionGroupMember], MemberAlreadyExistsException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=BN4PR12MB0803,RequestId=b392062c-5fec-4497-9136-71c1f5450110,TimeStamp=10/20/201
   5 4:37:07 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-MemberAlreadyExistsException] CD50CAA6,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Recipie
  ntTasks.AddDistributionGroupMember
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com

Comment: I tried removing the -erroraction but I get the same result. Something I noticed when I ran it locally (prior to that edit) was it errors out fine in the Powershell ISE. I gather this is because the command can't be run since I'm not connected to the exchange server via powershell. Not sure why using it on the server itself breaks it's error catching. Unless I need to do the checking a different way, such as for specific message out put.

Comment: Since you are seeing the output from the catch block, the try catch is working correctly. You just want to make it so that you don't see the error output?

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue here. We're seeing the error block but not the custom error message in the catch.

I need to trap when users can't be added (couldn't find the user) or any other specific error and dump these accounts to a CSV file...

EDIT:
Of course the moment I post this I find the answer... Adding -ErrorAction STOP makes it work properly, otherwise it simply shows the message and I guess doesn't return an errorcode... The actual message can be caught using this Catch

```
Catch{
    Echo $User $_.exception.Message
}
```